# image size in Multiple Screens

Tags: android, screen

Is there any  extra `drawable-folder` for those 5.1"WVGA devices?

In my application these  these devices are using the 
`drawable=large-hdpi`(which is for the 7 inch devices according to android documentation) folder images  and those images are too big.

Comment: did you try creating folder drawable-sw550dp or something similar and put your images there?

Comment: @ kaustuv  not working

Answer (score 0):

This device resolution should be 480x800 and should use **drawable-mdpi**.
For 7" devices make a new folder in res named **drawable-large-mdpi**.

Comment: yes,  you are  right , but its not using the images of  drawable-mdpi

Comment: its using drawable=large-hdpi

Comment: please read Question Carefully,you are going in  wrong direction